# Overload resolution based on concept with dependent parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, overload-resolution

I am trying to use concepts to overload templated functions whose argument depends on the template parameter. Unfortunately this fails on gcc, reporting an ambiguous overload.

In my project I have code that **compiles** in gcc 9.3 and **fails** in gcc 12.2. But in trying to minimize the code, I've ended up with this, which fails on both gcc versions, but works in clang 15.0.0:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    using value_type = int;
};
struct B
{
    using value_type = int;
};

template<typename Candidate>
concept something = requires {
    typename Candidate::value_type;
};
template<typename Candidate>
concept something_specific = something<Candidate> && std::is_same_v<Candidate, A>;

template<something T>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Something" << std::endl;
}
template<something_specific T>
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Something specific" << std::endl;
}

template<something T>
void bar(const typename T::value_type& s)
{
    std::cout << "Something: " << s << std::endl;
}
template<something_specific T>
void bar(const typename T::value_type& s)
{
    std::cout << "Something specific: " << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<B>(); // works
    foo<A>(); // works

    bar<B>(1); // works
    bar<A>(2); // ambiguous overload

    return 0;
}
```

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xsoo9qT3s), the error message is as expected:

```
<source>:48:11: error: call of overloaded 'bar<A>(int)' is ambiguous
   48 |     bar<A>(2); // ambiguous overload
      |     ~~~~~~^~~
<source>:32:6: note: candidate: 'void bar(const typename T::value_type&) [with T = A; typename T::value_type = int]'
   32 | void bar(const typename T::value_type& s)
      |      ^~~
<source>:37:6: note: candidate: 'void bar(const typename T::value_type&) [with T = A; typename T::value_type = int]'
   37 | void bar(const typename T::value_type& s)
      |      ^~~
```

I expected the `something_specific` overload to be chosen, because the concept that's restricting the template parameter is more specific. We can see this is true for `foo` already, otherwise it would be ambiguous as well.

Of course I can make it work with a `requires` clause, but I expected it to work as-is. So I'd like to understand whether this is just not supported or if it's a compiler issue. Is clang correct in compiling this code?

Comment: why would it not be ambiguous? Why do you expect one overload to be choosen by overload resolution and not the other?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I deleted the wrong comment... The answer was: the `something_specific` overload should be chosen because the concept that's restricting the template parameter is more specific. My understanding is that that's how it's supposed to work. Without this behavior, `foo` would not work either and clang could not work as well.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've added this reasoning to the question as requested (in the deleted comment?)

Comment: i am not requesting, only suggesting ;). Yes I deleted the comment, because I realized it could be misunderstood as implying your question would be too unclear, which it isnt

Comment: This looks like a GCC bug to me. I'd report and see what happens.

Comment: `T` is non deducible in `bar` which seems is problematic for gcc... [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MoGdoWfPb) with working `T*`(with `nullptr`) against `std::type_identity_t<T*>`.

Comment: Not sure here. Constraints are only considered if during partial ordering of function templates deduction _succeeds_ in both directions (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#6), but your function parameters are using the template parameters in non-deduced contexts, so that deduction would _fail_ in both directions per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#4.sentence-4. However, it is unclear to me whether "and is not explicitly specified" in the same sentence applies to the explicitly specified template arguments _in the call_ during partial ordering