Why is a requires clause not enough to disambiguate a function with dependent type?
In the following sample (try online), adding the trivial constraint requires true is enough to select the right overload when the argument is an int, but not enough when it's a dependent type. Both GCC and Clang show this.
My only guess is the use of a dependent name makes the overload resolution consider them ranked equal, but the only thing I've found on CPPReference is:

When determining if two dependent expressions are equivalent, only the dependent names involved are considered, not the results of name lookup (link).

This suggest to me that they would be considered the ranked equal, and then the concept rules would come in -- like they do for the int case?
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T> requires true
void Overloaded(int const&)
{ std::puts("int: concept"); }

template <typename T>
void Overloaded(int const&)
{ std::puts("int: non-concept"); }


template <typename T> requires true
void Overloaded(typename T::Arguments const&)
{ std::puts("concept"); }

template <typename T>
void Overloaded(typename T::Arguments const&)
{ std::puts("non-concept"); }


int main() {
    struct HasArgs {
        struct Arguments {};
    };

    Overloaded<HasArgs>(int{}); // ok
    Overloaded<HasArgs>(HasArgs::Arguments{}); // error
}

The (only somewhat helpful) error:
<source>:27:24: error: call of overloaded 'Overloaded<main()::HasArgs>(main()::HasArgs::Arguments)' is ambiguous
   27 |     Overloaded<HasArgs>(HasArgs::Arguments{}); // error
<source>:13:6: note: candidate: 'void Overloaded(const typename T::Arguments&) [with T = main()::HasArgs; typename T::Arguments = main()::HasArgs::Arguments]'
   13 | void Overloaded(typename T::Arguments const&)
<source>:17:6: note: candidate: 'void Overloaded(const typename T::Arguments&) [with T = main()::HasArgs; typename T::Arguments = main()::HasArgs::Arguments]'
   17 | void Overloaded(typename T::Arguments const&)


Potentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309975/overload-resolution-based-on-concept-with-dependent-parameter . The resolution was "probably a compiler bug", but I never got around to filing a bug to make sure. The fact that both clang and g++ reject it might point to it not being a bug though.
